# jQuery toggle failed to hide ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor-blaze

This Meteor code is expected to show and hide a `<ul id="Bulb">` element. An event fires the first time shows the element but when clicked again it failed to hid it.

Please note the browser `console.log($('#' + category))` image showing both events. Any idea why the second click not hiding the element and how to make it hide on the second event so that the toggle works?

Thank you.

```js
  'click .category': function(e){
    let category = e.target.innerText
    $('#' + category).toggle()
    console.log($('#' + category))
  }
```

```css
.horizontal {
  display: inline;
}
.group, .subGroup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
          <li class="category" data-category={{category}}> <img src="/{{category}}.svg"/>{{category}}
            
            <ul id={{category}} class="no-bullets group">
              <!-- the last word is the argument passed to the helper function -->
              {{#each categories category}} 
              <li class="horizontal" data-category={{category}}>{{this}}</li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
```

[image]

**Fix but with unwanted side effect**

The reason is that the first click gives a value to `e.target.innerText` which is different than the value it gets in the second click.

The second value includes all the "innerText" of all the `li` items which are now visible in the child `ul`.

So instead of using `let category = e.target.innerText` I used:

```
let category = e.target.getAttribute('data-category')
```

and this value does not change between click as did the innerText.

The problem side effect of this is that clicking the `li` elements inside the child `ul` triggers the toggle which is not what I want.

Comment: Hi, can you try like this `$(e.target).find("ul").toggle()` ?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. Adding `console.log(category)`, the first click prints "Bulb", the second click gives "Bulb and other text which is now visible". i.e the second value includes the innerText of the `ul`.

Comment: @Swati Yes that worked.